# Querying across hierarchical tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having issues querying a table with a subclass. To illustrate, if I had the following tables in a MySQL database

`userTable`:

```
id     name     gender_id 
1      bob      1
....
```

`genderTable`:

```
gender_id     term
1             male
2             female
....
```

How can I write a query for all of the males using `term` from `genderTable`, not just using the `gender_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a simple join. There is no hierarchy involved here, the `genderTable` is called a *referrential* table.

The following query will give you all users that with a `'male'` gender:

```
select u.*
from userTable u
inner join genderTable g 
    on  g.gender_id = u.gender_id 
    and g.term = 'male'
```